# My third div is acting very odd

Tags: html, css

Best to see the code for yourself. The server it's being hosted on is secure and unfortunately I'm not allowed to give out the password freely.

What's happening is I have three large divs that are theoretically supposed to be aligned one next to the other, but the third one drops down all the way to the bottom right, despite all my width values being added up to 100%. Thanks in advance everyone, as usual.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>INT222</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/mycss.css" type="text/css" media="screen" /> 
  </head>
  <body class = "body">
    <div class="bdiv">
        <nav class="nav">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="http://zenit.senecac.on.ca/~int222_122a07/">My Zenit Account</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://zenit.senecac.on.ca/~int222_122a07/assign2/index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://zenit.senecac.on.ca/~int222_122a07/assign2/gallery.html">Picture Gallery</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://zenit.senecac.on.ca/~int222_122a07/assign2/video.html">Video</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://zenit.senecac.on.ca/~int222_122a07/assign2/audio.html">Audio</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://zenit.senecac.on.ca/~int222_122a07/assign2/tables.html">Tables</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://zenit.senecac.on.ca/~int222_122a07/assign2/forms.html">Forms</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://zenit.senecac.on.ca/~int222_122a07/assign2/css/mycss.css">CSS Used</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://zenit.senecac.on.ca/~int222_122a07/assign2/other.html">Other</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
    <form method="post" action="https://zenit.senecac.on.ca/~int222_122a07/assign2/index.html" id="formex1">
        <div class = "left1">
                <h1 class = "mama">Mama's Pizza</h1> <br />
            <hr />
                <h1 class = "mama2">416 or 905 <br /> 222-6262</h1> <br />
            <hr />
                <table class="prices">
                    <tr>
                        <td>Small</td>
                        <td>$11.55</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Medium</td>
                        <td>$15.25</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Large</td>
                        <td>$22.00</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>X-Large</td>
                        <td>$25.00</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Toppings</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>$1.79 Each</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Plus 13% HST</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Free Delivery</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            <p>
                Your Price<br />
                <input type="text" name="total" value="" readonly="readonly" />
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class = "left2">
            <div class = "pdiv">      
                <fieldset><legend>Personal Information</legend> <br />
                    Name <input type = "text" name = "Name" /> <br />
                    Account No. <input maxlength="10" size="10" name = "account#" /> <br />
                    Phone No. <input maxlength = "12" size = "12" name = "Phone#" /> <br />
                    Date of Birth <input maxlength = "7" size = "7" name = "DOB" />
                </fieldset>
            </div>
            <div class = "pscdiv">
                <fieldset><legend>Pizza Size & Crust</legend> <br /> 
                    <p>
                        <select name="pizza-size" size="5">
                          <option value="1"> Select Pizza Size </option>
                          <option value="2"> Small </option>
                          <option value="3"> Medium </option>
                          <option value="4"> Large </option>
                          <option value="5"> X-Large </option>
                        </select>
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <select name="crust" size="3">
                          <option value="1"> Regular Crust </option>
                          <option value="2"> Thin Crust </option>
                          <option value="3"> Thick Crust </option>
                          <option value="4"> Whole Wheat Crust </option>
                        </select>
                    </p>
                </fieldset>
            </div>
            <div class = "csdiv">
                <fieldset><legend>Cheeses</legend> <br />
                  <p>
                    <input type = "radio" name = "Cheeses" value = "Mozzarella" />Mozzarella<br />
                    <input type = "radio" name = "Cheeses" value = "Reduced Fat" />Reduced Fat<br />
                    <input type = "radio" name = "Cheeses" value = "Feta" />Feta<br />
                  </p>
                </fieldset>
            </div>
            <div class = "cdiv">
                <fieldset><legend>Sauces</legend> <br />
                  <p>
                    <input type = "radio" name = "Sauces" value = "Pizza Sauce" />Pizza Sauce<br />
                    <input type = "radio" name = "Sauces" value = "BBQ Sauce" />BBQ Sauce<br />
                    <input type = "radio" name = "Sauces" value = "Garlic Sauce" />Garlic Sauce<br />
                  </p>
                </fieldset>
            </div> 
            <div class = "div6">
              <fieldset><legend>Special Instructions</legend> <br />
                <p>
                  <textarea name="Additional Comments" cols="32" rows="6"></textarea>       
                </p>
              </fieldset>
            </div>
            <div class = "srdiv">       
                <input type="submit" value="Place Your Order" />       
                <input type="reset"  value="Start Over" />
            </div>
        </div>
    <div class = "right">
        <fieldset><legend>Choose Toppings - $1.79 Each</legend> <br />
            <div class = "tdiv1">
                    <p>
                      <input type="checkbox" name="Toppings" value="1" />Anchovies<br />      
                      <input type="checkbox" name="Toppings" value="2" />Bacon<br />
                      <input type="checkbox" name="Toppings" value="3" />Ham<br />
                      <input type="checkbox" name="Toppings" value="4" />Pepperoni<br />
                      <input type="checkbox" name="Toppings" value="5" />Salami<br />
                      <input type="checkbox" name="Toppings" value="6" />Sausage<br />
                    </p>
            </div>
            <div class = "tdiv2">
                    <p>
                      <input type="checkbox" name="Toppings" value="7" />Broccoli<br />
                      <input type="checkbox" name="Toppings" value="8" />Green Olives<br />
                      <input type="checkbox" name="Toppings" value="9" />Green Peppers<br />
                      <input type="checkbox" name="Toppings" value="10" />Mushrooms<br />
                      <input type="checkbox" name="Toppings" value="11" />Red Onion<br />
                      <input type="checkbox" name="Toppings" value="12" />Roasted Garlic<br />
                    </p>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
    <br />
    </form>
</body>
</html> 

.body {
    width: 1024px;
    margin: auto;
}
.bdiv{
    position: relative;
    border: solid 2px;
}

.nav ul{
    list-style-type: none;
    overflow: hidden;

}
.nav ul li {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    padding: 0 25px;
}
.mdiv {
    position: relative;
    clear: both;
}
.h1 {
    text-align: left;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-style: italic;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    border-style: groove;
    padding: 4px;    
}
.div1 {
    background-color: #990000;
}
.subject {
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.div2 {
    width: 66%;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}
.div3 {
    width: 33%;
    position: relative;
    float: right;
}
.subject2 {
    font-size: 24px;
    font-family: monospace;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
}
.list1 {
    list-style-type: none;
}
footer {
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    clear: both;
    background-color:#990000;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

.fbody {
background-color:#0f0000;
width:1000px;
margin:auto;
color:#009900;
}

.left1{
    display:table;
    width: 20%;
    float: left;
    border: solid 2px #000000;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #000000;
}

.left2 {
    display:table;
    width: 35%;
    float: left;
    border: solid 2px #000000;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #000000;
}

.right {
    border: solid 2px #000000;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #000000;
    width: 45%;
    float: right;
    clear: both;
}

.prices {
    border: ridge 5px;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
}

.pscdiv1 {
    alignment-adjust: middle;
    display: table-row;
}

.srdiv {
    text-align: center;
}

.tdiv1 {
    float: left;
    border: none;
    padding: 20 0px;
}

.tdiv2 {
    margin-left: auto;
    text-align: justify;
    float: right;
    padding: 0 35px;
}
```

Comment: My advice, Do NOT use Tables, use floats and positions to place elements.

Comment: @jcho360 While in general this is true. I think there is a time and place for everything and Tables allow for quick.  Down and dirty placement of information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you have `clear:both` set on the final container. Also, it's best to use a standard `class="left"` on all 3 containers, and then set a different width for each individual container.

Using `float:left` and `float:right` together can cause unusual behaviour in such a case.

Finally, border is included into the width percentage, to workaround this you can use CSS3 and `box-sizing: border-box;` however it's a better idea to reduce your widths to 99%.

Here is an example fiddle from your code: [click](http://jsfiddle.net/W8Wtg/1/).

Answer (score 1):

Your divs are wrapping due to the internal size of the divs adding up to 100% of the widths.  You have however listed a border which adds to the width of a div and isn't factored into the % width.  You will need to factor in the border if you want to keep the divs from wrapping.

Comment: In conjunction with factoring in the border you will also need to do as @MartinAmps suggested and move the `clear:both;` into it's own div.  What I do just because I like how it reads is make a class of `.ClearBoth` and have a div containing nothing, but this class statement whenever I need to clear out the floats that I have.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/AwQ7t/ Here is a jsFiddle of the Div's floating and working as requested.  To allow the border to be in place you can simply take the % of one of the divs down by one.  Like... http://jsfiddle.net/AwQ7t/1/  (I also changed to float left for 3rd div, but this will be based on your preference)

Comment: The div needs to float right though, so the problem still occurs.

Comment: @learnenburn just curious... Whats the reason for required float right if your ideal situation is no gap?  At that point float left/right would be indifferent.

Answer (score 0):

If you change the .right width to 44% it works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

The spaces/newlines between the elements are adding extra width. Remove them (so it looks like `</div><div class="div2">`) and it should be fine. If not, try adding `box-sizing: border-box` to make the borders get included in the width.

Comment: the `box-sizing:border-box` is cool I hadn't heard of that before.  Is there good cross browser support for this?

Comment: @Jared It's pretty widely supported, you can use `-webkit-box-sizing` for chrome/webkit based browsers and `-moz-box-sizing` for Gecko based browsers for a full list of support see [http://caniuse.com/css3-boxsizing](http://caniuse.com/css3-boxsizing).

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying your `.right` class to:

```
.right {
    border: solid 2px #000000;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #000000;
    width: 44%;
    float:left;
}
```

Comment: As I've mentioned above, the right class is for this particular div to be floating right.

Comment: Understand, but what I suggested behaves similar to the accepted answer. Though, I do agree that using the "left" class for all containers is more semantic.